# master master replication MySQL performance

Tags: mysql

I currently have a MySQL instance on a 16 core 60gig ram server. The instance is constantly receiving a high volume of inserts and updates based on traffic to our websites and applications. the problem is when reports are run or heavy crons this causes the server to struggle and inserts start hitting lock timeouts.

I have had a look at clustering but this I believe is too advanced at the moment for us. I would like to clear up some issues I have with the concept of master-master replication (2x 16core 60gig).

1) Can I use one master for writes and updates and the other for heavy reads and will this help with my performance issue?

2) If one master goes down does the other continue to function, moreover when the downed master comes back online does it recover the transactions it missed from the other master?

3) Can I run 4 masters, 2 being fail overs for the other 2 ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do not need the answers after 1 year but just for others with similar problem.

We use one master for heavy updates + 3 replicas for heavy reads from our applications.

Replication is quite robust. If master is not reachable (also due to networking problems sometimes) for a short time replicas resynchronized itself after master is up again.

If some replica dies or is unreachable for longer time future sync depends on how long it was "dead". For replica be able to sync master has to have old binary logs still present. If they were already deleted you will have to recreate replica. (This can be also a problem if master is unreachable for all replicas but running and receiving updates. So do not try to save money on disk capacity...)

More masters + replicas are better. You can either fork updates to more independent masters. Or set master to master replication - works well I used it for some time.

In case of quite often networking problems I recommend to fiddle with setting - see here - http://mysql.freeideas.cz/subdom/mysql/2016/08/16/mysql-replication-troubleshooting-lags-on-replicas/

I can highly recommend to use monitoring in prometheus + grafana with mysql_exporter (https://github.com/prometheus/mysqld_exporter) + Percona dashboards (https://github.com/percona/grafana-dashboards). It allows you to see delays in replication in real time and new Grafana 4.0 even allows you to set alerting on it. Makes your life easier :-)